# Why does cPanel not grant access to my user even with all privileges allowed?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

This is been driving me nuts for days. I created a database in cPanel, with a user and enabled all the privileges checkboxes.

Now whenever I try accessing my database, it doesn't work and the errorlog show:

**PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '

graphgr1_mhazaa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I tried acessing the database locally from the command line

```
  mysql -u myUsername -pMyPassword -h remoteHostIP -D databaseName
```

and it showed:

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'c-174-53-152-193.hsd1.mn.comcast.net' (using password: YES)**

I even tried to access the database as root

```
 mysql.exe -u root -h remoteHostIp -D databaseName
```

Same message. I'm pretty sure I got all the spelling/names right, and tried it on different computers too. So any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '
>   graphgr1_mhazaa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

To connect from a script in your cPanel account to a database also in your cPanel account you need to just

1. Create Database
2. Create User for it
3. Give necessary grants to the User

To connect locally, from your own computer to a cPanel hosted database you need to:

1. Have a Database and an User assigned to it.
2. Allow your local computer's IP in cPanel's Remote MySQL tool

The way that cPanel hosted MySQL works is that it requires all MySQL connections to be from authorized IP addresses.

What allows you to connect your scripts from your cPanel account to your cPanel hosted databases is that the server's IP address is already present in the Remote MySQL tool.

Using SSH you can connect just by using

```
mysql -u YOUR_USER -p YOUR_DATABASE ## MySQL added User connection, sees only databases it has access to
mysql -u cPanel_USER -p             ## cPanel User connection, sees all databases added in your cPanel account
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a a database, user, and permissions set up, but I didn't add authorization for my IP addresses so that's probably the problem. I'm a little confused how I'd go  about doing that though. Do I go to cPanel -> Remote MySQL -> Add Access Host and just put my ip address in there?

Comment: That's right. Since the WildCard symbol in MySQL is % not * you can use it to match a range of IPs. If your IP is 1.1.1.1 you can simply add it in Remote MySQL (scr: https://prnt.sc/jzi4sa). You can also add any IPs of the 1.1.1 like 1.1.1.% . This will allow connections from your IP to the server's MySQL databases. You still need an User with privileges to access a Database

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different take on this.

I managed to access my MySql database using Sequel Pro on my Mac laptop by generating a SSH key in cpanel and copying this (the id_rsa file) onto my Mac.

It wont then work unless you change the permission on this file to 400

```
chmod 400 filename
```

However, once Sequel Pro was working I then tried to read my database via python using pymsql.

This gave rise to no end of problems and threw several variants of the error under discussion.

After an immense amount of fiddling about with mysql in the terminal window I gave up and turned to a local UNIX guru who came up with the following solution.

In the terminal type

```
ssh -i id_rsa -L 3307:yourcpanel.hosted.xxx:3306 yourcpanelusername@your cpanel.hosted.xxx -N
```

For more info search for ‘ssh port forward only no shell’

As far as I understand it, it opens a local port number 3307 on the Mac and connects to cpanel on port 3306 using the id_rsa key and disallows commands. Once this up and running...

In your python code use some variant on this

```
db = pymysql.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PWD, db=DB_NAME,  port=DB_PORT)
```

where 
DB_HOST = ‘localhost’, DB_USER = your cpanel database username, DB_PWD = your database password, DB_NAME = name of your cpanel database, DB_PORT = 3307